# How to filter DataDrame and generate multiple Excel files with Multiple sheets

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I'm trying to create multiple Excel files and each file with multiple worksheets.
below is the code snippets:

```
for file in district:
    for prd in product:
        with pd.ExcelWriter(folder+"//Output//"+file+"_{}.xlsx".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))) as xlWriter:
            df_district=df[df["SalesDistrict"].isin([file]) & df["ProductSold"].isin([prd])].copy()
            df_district.to_excel(xlWriter,index_label="SalesDate",sheet_name=prd)
```

this will only produce the last dataframe being read into the Excel writer?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to swap lines 2 and 3:

```
for file in district:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(folder+"//Output//"+file+"_{}.xlsx".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))) as xlWriter:
        for prd in product:
            df_district=df[df["SalesDistrict"].isin([file]) & df["ProductSold"].isin([prd])].copy()
            df_district.to_excel(xlWriter,index_label="SalesDate",sheet_name=prd)
```

Helper:

```
For each 'district':
   Create a 'district' file:
   For each 'product'
       Create a 'product' sheet in the 'district' file
```

Answer (score 0):

amended and it working now.

```
for file in district:
    
    xlWriter= pd.ExcelWriter(folder+"//Output//"+file+"_{}.xlsx".format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")),engine='xlsxwriter')

    for prd in product:
            df_district=df[df["SalesDistrict"].isin([file]) & df["ProductSold"].isin([prd])].copy()
            df_district.to_excel(xlWriter,index_label="SalesDate",sheet_name=prd) 
    
    xlWriter.save()
    xlWriter.close()
```

Comment: You can use context manager to avoid `save` and `close` operations. Check my answer, please.